# PowerShell to Remove Users in Site Collection with Permissions set to NONE

Tags: permissions

I did an export of a subweb and imported it to a new top level site collection. To keep all the unique permission on all folders and files, I had to use -IncludeUserSecurity, which has brought over all users from the previous site collection. For example, I have 200 users with access throughout broken/uniquely permissioned items in the site, but 400 users have no access via groups, so I need to purge those 400 users without accidentally removing any of the 200 that would show as limited access at the root, because they are added somewhere deep below.

I thought of doing this with something like a  foreach $user in $users and then delete the user if the site collection permission level is set to none, but I am unsure how to get the clean reference of the permission level "none".

Can someone help me with this script? Again, I would need to read in all site collection users into the array, and then delete the user if they have a permission level of none.

Additionally, can this be done with groups the same way?

Edit: So far I have this to capture the accounts that have permissions.

```
$site = Get-SPSite 'https://site'
Get-SPUser -web $site.URL -Limit All | select UserLogin, @{name="Roles";expression={$_.Roles}}, @{name="Roles in groups";expression={$_.Groups | %{$_.Roles}}},Groups | Where-Object {$_.Roles -ne $null -or ($_.Groups | %{$_.Roles}) -ne $null}
```

Edit 2: Looks like I can return null properly by checking if $*.Roles.count -eq 0. Turns out that the output was dirty, so checking for the string of "Contributor", "Full Control", etc is not reliable, and needed to use -like, which does not help with $null. Even when using $*.Roles.name, it mostly worked for the string value of "Contributor", etc., but some of the values were returned wrapped in curly braces {} and still go through when checking for $null. Not sure if the account records are corrupt or not. Anyway, .count is clean. Thanks to a friend that pointed this out.

```
$UsersWithoutPermissions = Get-SPUser -web $site.URL -Limit All | select UserLogin, @{name="Roles";expression={$_.Roles}}, @{name="Roles in groups";expression={$_.Groups | %{$_.Roles}}}, Groups | Where-Object {$_.Roles.count -eq 0 -and ($_.Groups | %{$_.Roles}) -eq $null}
```

Answer (score 2):

Complete! For anyone else this may help, send me $1,000, lol.

Okay, you can have it.

```
# Add SharePoint snap-in for use in standard PowerShell console
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue
# Allow global assignment of values
Start-SPAssignment -Global
        $site = Get-SPSite 'http://domain.com'
        $UserList = Get-SPUser -web $site.URL -Limit All | select UserLogin, @{name="Roles";expression={$_.Roles}}, @{name="Roles in groups";expression={$_.Groups | %{$_.Roles}}}, Groups      
        $UsersWithPermissions = Get-SPUser -web $site.URL -Limit All | select UserLogin, @{name="Roles";expression={$_.Roles}}, @{name="Roles in groups";expression={$_.Groups | %{$_.Roles}}}, Groups | Where-Object {$_.Roles -ne $null -or ($_.Groups | %{$_.Roles}) -ne $null}
        $UsersWithoutPermissions = Get-SPUser -web $site.URL -Limit All | select UserLogin, @{name="Roles";expression={$_.Roles}}, @{name="Roles in groups";expression={$_.Groups | %{$_.Roles}}}, Groups | Where-Object {$_.Roles.count -eq 0 -and ($_.Groups | %{$_.Roles}) -eq $null}
        $a = 0
        $b = 0
        $c = 0
        foreach ($x in $UserList)
        {
            $a = $a + 1
        }
        foreach ($y in $UsersWithPermissions)
        {
            $b = $b + 1
        }
        foreach ($z in $UsersWithoutPermissions)
        {
            $c = $c + 1
            Remove-SPUser $z.UserLogin -web $site.URL -Confirm:$False
            Write-Output "$($z.UserLogin) has been removed."
        }

        Write-Output "`nNumber of accounts: $a"
        Write-Output "`nNumber of accounts with Permission: $b"
        Write-Output "`nNumber of accounts without Permission: $c"
Stop-SPAssignment -Global
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in my UAT environmenet, and my results show it didn't account for unique permissions items. I think this still needs some work to be complete.
In my test cases, the users granted privileges to unique permssions items were also deleted.
 Close but no cigar.